# How do I repeat my initial input code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a calculator in python as one of my assignments for class (basic operations, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division) I have a print menu from which the user can choose what operation they want to use... and then enter their integers and an print statement of what the answer is.  My problem is that I need to repeat my initial input of what operation the user would like to execute.  New to programming so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
print ("1 = addition")
print ("2 = subtraction")
print ("3 = multiplication")
print ("4 = division")
print ("5 = Exit program\n")

x = int (input ("What operation would you like to perform?: ")) #prompts user for operation

if (x == 1): #if operation chose is addition then this line will exacute
  int1 = input ("Enter first integer: ")
  int1 = int (int1)
  int2 = input ("Enter second integer: ")
  int2 = int (int2)
  sum = int1 + int2
  print ("Sum is:", sum)

elif (x == 2): #if operation chose is subtraction then this line will exacute
  int1 = input ("Enter first integer: ")
  int1 = int (int1)
  int2 = input ("Enter second integer: ")
  int2 = int (int2)
  dif = int1 - int2
  print ("Difference is:", dif)

elif (x == 3): #if operation chose is multiplication then this line will exacute
  int1 = input ("Enter first integer: ")
  int1 = int (int1)
  int2 = input ("Enter second integer: ")
  int2 = int (int2)
  mult = int1 * int2
  print ("Multiplication is:", mult)

elif (x == 4): #if operation chose is division then this line will exacute
  int1 = input ("Enter first integer: ")
  int1 = int (int1)
  int2 = input ("Enter second integer: ")
  int2 = int (int2)
  div = int1 / int2
  print ("Division is: %.2f" % div)

elif (x == 5):
  print ("goodbye")
  quit()
```

Comment: Are you running Python 2 or 3? You have both tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split that code into a function:

```
print "1 = addition"
print "2 = subtraction"
print "3 = multiplication"
print "4 = division"
print "5 = Exit program\n"

def maths(choice):
    if choice == 1: #if operation chose is addition then this line will exacute
       int1 = input("Enter first integer:")
       int2 = input ("Enter second integer: ")
       sum = int1 + int2
       print "Sum is:", sum

    elif choice == 2: #if operation chose is subtraction then this line will exacute
       int1 = input("Enter first integer: ")
       int2 = input("Enter second integer: ")
       dif = int1 - int2
       print "Difference is:", dif

    elif choice == 3: #if operation chose is multiplication then this line will exacute
       int1 = input("Enter first integer: ")
       int2 = input("Enter second integer: ")
       mult = int1 * int2
       print "Multiplication is:", mult

    elif choice == 4: #if operation chose is division then this line will exacute
       int1 = input("Enter first integer: ")
       int2 = input ("Enter second integer: ")
       div = int1 / int2
       print "Division is: %.2f" % div

    elif choice == 5:
       print "goodbye"
       quit()

while True: # "While True, repeat everything below":
    maths(input("What operation would you like to perform?: "))
```

---

Edit: It seems you have stated that it's python 2.7, so I cleaned the code for you.

You do not need int(int1) and int(int2) because input() does not make the input a string. i.e:

```
>>> number = input('Enter a number! ') # Let's say I put 5
>>> print number
5 # Notice it's not a string (no ' ')
```

Whereas raw_input() would do:

```
>>> number = raw_input('Enter a number! ')
>>> print number
'5' # 5 is a string, not an integer. And so int() would be required
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's Python 3, since `print()` is a function, and there's no imports from `__future__`

Comment: @Volatility is this towards me or should this comment be at the top where another user asked if it was 2 or 3

Comment: Well I guess it's towards both of you, but you mentioned `raw_input()` so it's mainly directed to you. I agree it's a little confusing having both tags there.

Comment: @Volatility I put back the int()

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was trying to look for!

Comment: @JulioRamirez No problem. I also edited my answer to reflect with you saying it's python 2.7 and not python 3

Answer (score 1):

use a `while` loop:

Now this will loop again and again until `x` is not equal to 5

```
while True:
    #your code

    elif x == 5:       # no need of () around conditions
    print ("goodbye")
    break             # exit the while loop
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out! I was trying the while loop inside the operation code instead of at the beginning of the whole program!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on basic flow control. Here's the relevant [python tutorial section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

This can be implemented using a `for` or a `while` loop. Here's examples of both:

```
for a in range(10):
    print a

b=0
while b<0:
    print b
    b= b+1
```